# How to enable persistent option in disk creator?

Tags: usb, installation, persistence, usb-creator

I try to test natty alpha with usb. (my system is 10.04) But when I run disk creator I can not choose the option for persistent creation. Here on screenshots I saw that this is possible. Choosing the second option "Burn your CD or create a USB drive"

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download
When I create live usb without persistent options I can not activate my nvidia drivers and 3D support for unity because after restart settings are lost.
  [image]

Comment: how large is the disk you are trying to use?

Comment: My usb disk is about 4GB

Comment: I have idea to use windows then run wubi installer and select usb for installation place but I don't have windows at all. :)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the `Make Startup Disk` window? (Yours, **not** the one on http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)

Comment: Hmmm, shouldn't your usb drives have labels?

Comment: What happens if you select `/dev/sdb1` instead? I have a Sandisk USB drive and when I plug it in it mounts as a CD and a USB stick.

Comment: I use san disk too. I already tried both items every time the same problem I can't choose persistent option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are experiencing this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/557775)? See if the workaround described in [comment #4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/557775/comments/4) works for you:

> I came up with a workaround:
>
> Copy your ISO image to /tmp or
> somewhere else not automatically
> destected by usb-creator.
>
> Choose 'Other' and select that ISO
>
> Select that image from the listing
>
> Now it's not greyed out anymore and
> you can also go back to select your
> original image and it will be good.
>
> Voilá!

Comment: This answer is working for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 12.04 anymore. ):

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, the persistent partition is mounted **after** the root partition is mounted - so you are out of luck.

A workaround is to remaster the ISO and install `nvidia-current` package on it - you can download the package for remastering [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/remastersys/files/remastersys-ubuntu-karmic-lucid/). Once it offers to go into console, do so and run `apt-get install nvidia-current`. You can then create a new USB with the ISO it produces (usually located in your home directory). Note that you might need 4-5 GB of free space (the final ISO is ~700 megs, though)

Comment: Hmm remastersys doesn't offer me to go in to console. I see this is the only to get drivers installed. You were right disk creator create only live disks without possibility to add software to the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I find the USB creator to be a bit buggy sometimes, but here's how it usually works for me:

- Select `/dev/sdb`,
- Click on 'Erase Disk > Yes' ('Datenträger Löschen > Ja'),
- Wait a bit until that red exclamation mark next to '/dev/sdb1' disappears,
- Select `/dev/sdb1` - now you should be able to choose the amount of persistent space.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the extra space option of usb-creator working you can always make a persistent partition.
Unlike the maximum 4GB persistence allowed by using a casper-rw FAT32 file, persistence size is only limited by drive size.

Boot Live CD.

Plug in flash drive.

Start Partition Editor

Create 1 GB FAT32 partition, (on the left side of the bar). (size is optional)
Create a 1.5 GB ext3 partition to the right of this, labeled it "casper-rw". (ext2 and ext4 also work).

Create a partition in the remaining space and label it "home-rw". (optional, creates a separate home partition)

Close Partition Editor.

Un-mount and re-mount flash drive.

Start "Create a live usb startup disk", (usb-creator).
Select "Discard on shutdown".

Press "Make Startup Disk.

When usb-creator finishes, run "gksu nautilus"

Select disk / syslinux / text.cfg and add "persistent" as shown below:

append  noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz quiet splash --

Shutdown, remove CD, reboot.