# How do I create a USB Startup Disk with the nvidia drivers installed?

Tags: unity, nvidia, 11.04

I'm trying to test natty with unity from an ubuntu usb key but need the nvidia drivers installed to run unity on my XPS M1330.  When I try to activate the drivers as I would normally do there is an error activating them.  I'm assuming that this is because I can't update the usb key, but I'm not sure.  How do I install the nvidia drivers on the ubuntu usb key so that I can use it to test natty with unity?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is a link to the error message I receive

https://gist.github.com/728853

Comment: Your question is related to mine http://askubuntu.com/questions/16112/how-to-enable-persistent-option-in-disk-creator

Comment: Now I made persistent usb disk. But I get error too. Can not activate drivers.

Comment: [New user here - who can't yet add my own comments] I'm in exactly the same boat - I came across remastersys, but this warning on it's own page told me it wouldn't be suitable
"You should not install any proprietary video drivers like the nvidia or ati drivers as they will not be used on the livecd and users will have to reinstall them after installation." The persistent option on the USB creator seems to make no difference either. Thus I'm not sure that there is a solution - a disappointing conclusion, but one nonetheless.

Comment: Hi I am finally on natty with usb. Installed it from another live usb device. And then installed nvidia drivers. So alpha unity is very fast. :)

Comment: So just want to make sure I've got this straight.  You got it working by installing natty on a usb stick, while booted from a second live usb stick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked one of the installer maintainers of an easy way to do this and he mentioned to me that you should be able to create a USB stick, then boot off of it, and then plug in another USB stick and install from the first stick onto the second one.

After that boot off the first stick and then you can do what you want to it, like  installing nvidia/ATI drivers.

I tried it with a nightly ISO but never got the 2nd stick to boot but it should be possible if someone wants to try it out. If someone can get this working I think it would really help 11.04 testing.

Comment: FYI, Jono Bacon has a video of how to do this in his latest broadcast http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/11324660.  You need to listen to him chat for a while though...

Comment: @MarkB Yeah but the stick isn't persistent, if you install the drivers and reboot they go away. :(

Comment: the first stick won't be persistent but the second stick you create with it should be.  After using the first disc to install on the second, I just did a full update and enabled the nvidia drivers.  Everything seems to be running properly now, though it's noticably slower off my poor USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to find something that might help (I haven't tried this my self) called Remastersys there is a how-to on psycho cats site
[nuts feline tutorial about remastersys](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/remastersys)

basically it will make your current install into an ISO so you might want to exclude your home directory although it probably does this by default. The main thing is if you have the restricted Invidia driver installed it will be added to the ISO.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried remastersys and it is quite slow, although it will do the job if you're patient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try reserving extra space before making the start-up disk.

If you have already done that, when does the error occur and what is the error?

Comment: I reserved 512 MB. I'll try reserving more and see if I can also get more details on the error.

Comment: I've tried again and have the details of the error message.  Here's a gist of the whole console output https://gist.github.com/728853