# How to add nvidia-current drivers into an iso file with remastersys?

Tags: unity, nvidia, 11.04, 3d, remastersys

It is necessary to use 3D drivers with Unity Desktop 11.04. How can I create my own iso disk to burn it on usb drive for testing Unity. I have some problems to test unity in Virtual box also default Ubuntu Disk Creator doesn't work for me to make usable installation on usb.

I am searching the internet without success for how to add files, or - for example - the nvidia-current driver, to an iso. Only topics like "create you own custom distribution" but those topics don't fit the content :) :(

I can not report bugs without possibility to test natty with unity.

Comment: Serious question. :) isn't

Comment: Hi alfalive, this looks similair to an issue I'm having with nvidia and natty on usb.  I can boot from usb but can't install the nvidia drivers to try out unity.  I asked yesterday but haven't received a reply. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16192/how-do-i-create-a-usb-startup-disk-with-the-nvidia-drivers-installed/16221

Comment: @Mark B If you want to test natty buy 2 usb disks. One for live or instead live cd and one for installing natty on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, at least there is no easy or official way to do so. Remastersys doesn't enable you to bundle proprietary drivers:

> You should start with a clean install of Ubuntu or variant and use a single user to make all changes.  You should not install any proprietary video drivers like the nvidia or ati drivers as they will not be used on the livecd and users will have to reinstall them after installation. ([source](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/ubuntu.html))

However, you can add files to the installation. Any file that is put in `/etc/skel` will be copied to the home folder of each user on the installation. So you could potentially bundle the dependencies of [nvidia-current](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/nvidia-current) and add the .deb installer.